# Output .pdf does not exist - error when i knit my rmd file to pdf

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am having the following error when I knit my rmd file to pdf in Rmarkdown

**Output created**: `Academics/PhD Resources/MMED/rabiesElimination/Writing/Report_V7.pdf`

> Error in tools::file_path_as_absolute(output_file) :    file
>   'C:/Users/bkamangira/Documents/Academics/PhD
>   Resources/MMED/rabiesElimination/Writing/Report_V7.pdf' does not exist

In addition: **Warning message**:

> `In readLines(logfile) : incomplete final line found on 'Report_V7.log'`

Comment: Are other outputs fine? like html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realised my error was that I had not installed a tex software. I accomplished this by running the `install.package(tinytex)` command and the `install_tinytex()` function to have the tex software for use with r-markdown installed